# running htmlunit on a servlet

Tags: servlets, htmlunit

I am wanting to use htmlunit to scrape data from a website. I am passing the address as an attribute from a form. I keep getting errors, it says the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient" even though I have the .jar files imported and the javadoc file location set correctly. Am I missing something?

```
package coreservlets;

import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

@WebServlet("/WebScrape")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WebScrape extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

    // Create and initialize WebClient object
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    String Address = (String) request.getAttribute("address");
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(Address);
    final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"LDPOffMarketPropertyInfo\"]//div//ul//li[4]//span[1]//text()");

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
              "<html>\n" +
              "<head>\n" +
              "<meta name=" + "\"viewport\" " +  "content=" + "\"initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\" " + "/>\n" +
              "<style type=" + "\"text/css\">\n" +
                "  html { height: 100% }\n" +
                "  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }\n" +
                "  #default { height: 800px;\n"+
                "            width: 400px;  }\n" +
                "  </style>\n" + div);

    }   


}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "I have the .jar files imported". Where have you put the jar files?

Comment: And are you sure you have *all* the required libraries? How are you specifying the classpath?

Comment: I used the build class path .. and added the external .jar files (which I put in the project folder) but used add external since I wanted the path to be absolute. I added the entire contents of the htmlunit .zip file that I downloaded from their site. I also specified the javadoc location.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use Eclipse, the build path is just that: the set of libraries used to *build* the application.

You also need the libraries to be available at *runtime*, inside your webapp. The servlet specification explains where the libraries of a webapp must go: in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Remove the jar files from the build path, and drop them in the folder `WEB-INF/lib` of your WebContent directory. This will automatically add them back to the build path, and also make them part of the deployed application, and thus available at runtime.

They will also appear under the *Web App libraries* node in the package explorer of Eclipse, confirming that these libraries are part of the webapp.

Comment: I did as you said, but they are not automatically being added to the build path. Should I add them manually again, and have them in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: No. Make sure to refresh the project, and they will appear.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I followed your instructions exactly, but it is not appearing in the build path

Comment: Do you have any compilation issue? If not, then they're in the build path, hidden behind the entry "WebApp Libraries".

Comment: I figured it out. You have to add it to the WEB-INF/lib folder like you said, but then import .jars thorugh the build path as well. Then using Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add> Java Build Path Entries, it seems to work

Comment: You really shouldn't have to do that. Your project is a Dynamic Web Project, right?

Comment: Yes it is. I am not sure why it was not dynamically adding the .jar files located in my WEB-INF/lib file to the Library